# Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript

How do I check if the element I am clicking on has a classlist?

```
let dropdown  = target.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('form__select-dropdown')
```

My code is erroring on this line when the element that I click on doesn't have a class attached to it.

Which makes complete sense.

However I only want the below code to run if the nextElementSibling has the class form__select-dropdown:

```
        if (!selectTag && dropdown) {
            target.querySelector('.form__select-dropdown').classList.remove('active')
        } else {
            target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active')
        }
```

So I need to check if the target.nextElementSibling.classList exists before I do my condition to avoid the error but I'm unsure how to do this?

Comment: First check if the element exists first... `if (target.nextElementSibling)`

Comment: can you also post your html and js handler too.

Comment: All elements have `classList`. check if the element is non-null.

Comment: Yes it does return null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that  `target` doesn't always have a `nextElementSibling`; you should check if it is `null` before proceeding.

```
let next = target.nextElementSibling
let dropdown = next && next.classList.contains('form__select-dropdown')
```

---

And later in your code:

```
    if (!selectTag && dropdown) {
        target.querySelector('.form__select-dropdown').classList.remove('active')
    } else {
        next && next.classList.toggle('active')
    }
```

Comment: Well, this not only avoids `undefined`, but also `null`, `0`, `NaN`, 0-length ucs-2 string and `false`, which replies more correctly, as `null` is the default value for `HTMLElement#nextElementSibling`. But anyways... maybe the problem is that an event is firing one element's children

Comment: I know. Sometimes terseness takes precedence over specificity. Many DOM properties and methods, by the spec, can only return `null` (falsy) or a DOM node (truthy), so the check never produces false positives. I probably should have explained my logic more thoroughly, though.